# Truecrypt fails to unmount

Tags: ubuntu, truecrypt, device

With a recent package and kernel update truecrypt refuses to unmount drives with

> device-mapper: remove ioctl failed:
>   Device or resource busy Command failed

(worked fine before) Ubuntu 10.10
I use the lastest version 7.0a of truecrypt and even build the binary but without change.

Any ideas ?
Thanks
Sven

Comment: Hi, I did what the 1st answer( By John) asked to do. But still the problem is not solved.Still I can't unmount the mounted TrueCrypt volum. I'm using TrueCrypt 7.0a in Ubuntu 10.10. It was working fine until I install the recent updates of Ubuntu. Please help me.

Comment: I usually get that error if something is accessing the drive. i.e transmission-bt is running. 

Any chance the update started something that's accessing your drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, do the following in the TrueCrypt GUI in Ubunto:

Go to Setting > Preferences > System Integration > Kernel Services and check the box "Do not use kernel cryptographic services"

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can unmount from command line:

```
sudo umount /media/truecrypt8
```

Then dismount it from TrueCrypt GUI.